# Sorting array of custom objects based on optional string property in Swift

Tags: swift, string, sorting, option-type

I am trying to sort an array in swift of type 'ObjCClass' which is an objective c class. 'ObjCClass' has property 'name' which is an optional of type String. I want to sort the objects in the array in ascending order based on the 'name' property. How can I do this without force unwrapping?

I've tried using this:

```
var sortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted(by: { $0.name as String! < $1.name as String!})
```

I've been trying to use the guard and if/let statements to check if the property 'name' exists but I keep running into errors since I don't think I am doing it properly. How can I check if the property exists for every object in the array and then do the sorting?

Comment: The entries with a nil name, I just want to skip them and not have them in my sorted array.

Answer (score 5):

First filter out the unwanted entries, then compare `name` with a force-unwrap

```
var sortedArray = unsortedArray
    .filter { $0.name != nil }
    .sorted { $0.name! < $1.name! }
```

NOTE:

- Force unwrap is fine in this circumstance because `filter` removes the `nil` cases, and by the time we come to `sorted`, `name` **has** to be present